# ReactJs multiple functions call inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My target is to call multiple functions onClick. Assume that some of them has taken event and some value, so it is unable to call them in single function. How can I achieve that?

```
render() {
    //describe first function (1)
    const amountSelectClearInput = function(event) {
        // call two functions here
        this.amountSelect(event);
        this.clearInput();
    }.bind(this);
    var self = this;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {amounts.map(function (name, index) {
                    return <input type="button" value={name}
                                  className={self.state.active === name ? 'active' : ''}
                                  //here I must call () => self.changeClass(name) (1), and amountSelectClearInput (2)
                                  onClick={() => self.changeClass(name)} key={ name }/>;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I need to call `amountSelectClearInput` and `() => self.changeClass(name)` at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={function() { amountSelectClearInput(event);  self.changeClass(name)}}
```

Comment: One issue with this approach is that it's harder to test. Instead of stubbing a single method you need to stub two. Also, if you're going to do it like this, you should define `event` as a parameter on the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks! You're good at being rude and condescending. Useful, I'm sure.